# How to fix error "contractor can't be apply upload to given types"?

Tags: java

So i've been asked to create a simple solar system simulator for my coursework. Our lecturer has set out very specific guidelines in terms of the structure of constructors and methods of our classes.

Mostly I've managed to write the program without appearing of the errors, but still there's part of the code which I don't know how to change to make it work according the task.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SolarSystem {
    private String solarName;
    private static double luminosity;
    private ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<>();   

    public void setSolarSystem (String solarName, double luminosity) {
        this.solarName = solarName;
        SolarSystem.luminosity = luminosity;
    }
    public String getsolarName() {
        return solarName;
    }
    public String getsolarname(){
        return solarName;
    }
    public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
        Planet newPlanet = new Planet(name, mass, distance);
        planetList.add(newPlanet);
    }
    public String toString(){
        return getsolarName() + "\n" + 
               "Planet "+ Planet.getPlanetname() +
               " has a mass of " + Planet.getma() + 
               " Earths, is " + Planet.getdist() + 
               " from its star, and orbits in " + Planet.getPeriod() +
               " years: could be habitable? " + Planet.getHabitable() + "\n";

    }
    public static double getLuminosity() {
        return luminosity;
    }
    public static void setLuminosity(double luminosity) {
        SolarSystem.luminosity = luminosity;
    }

    static class Planet {
        private static String planetname;
        private static double ma;
        private static double dist;
        private static double period;
        private static String habitable;
        private double sqlum;
        private static double luminos;
        SolarSystem system;
        public Planet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
            setPlanetname(name);
            ma=mass;
            dist=distance;
            SolarSystem.setLuminosity(luminos);
            period = Math.sqrt(distance*distance*distance);
            sqlum = Math.sqrt(luminos);
            if ((ma >= 0.6) && (ma<= 7.0) && 
                (dist>=0.75*sqlum) && (dist<=2.0*sqlum) ) {
                habitable = "yes";
            }
            else {
                habitable = "no";
            }
        }
        public static String getdist() {
            return null;
        }
        public static String getma() {
            return null;
        }
        public static String getPlanetname() {
            return planetname;
        }
        public void setPlanetname(String planetname) {
            Planet.planetname = planetname;
        }
        public static double getPeriod() {
            return period;
        }
        public void setPeriod(double period) {
            Planet.period = period;
        }
        public static String getHabitable() {
            return habitable;
        }
        public static void setHabitable(String habitable) {
            Planet.habitable = habitable;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Automatic Test our lecturer uses:

```
//Uncomment if using extra tests
//import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

/*This is the automatic test class for CS-110 coursework 2. The output of the student's program
 * under test should match the string TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN
 */
public class AutoTest {

static final String TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN = "Our System\n"
        + "Planet Mercury has a mass of 0.055 Earths, is 0.387AU from its star, and orbits in 0.241 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Venus has a mass of 0.815 Earths, is 0.723AU from its star, and orbits in 0.615 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Earth has a mass of 1.0 Earths, is 1.0AU from its star, and orbits in 1.0 years: could be habitable? yes\n"
        + "Planet Mars has a mass of 0.107 Earths, is 1.52AU from its star, and orbits in 1.874 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Jupiter has a mass of 317.8 Earths, is 5.2AU from its star, and orbits in 11.858 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Saturn has a mass of 95.2 Earths, is 9.58AU from its star, and orbits in 29.652 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Uranus has a mass of 14.5 Earths, is 19.2AU from its star, and orbits in 84.13 years: could be habitable? no\n"
        + "Planet Neptune has a mass of 17.1 Earths, is 30.05AU from its star, and orbits in 164.728 years: could be habitable? no\n";

static final String TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1 = "Trappist 1\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1b has a mass of 1.017 Earths, is 0.012AU from its star, and orbits in 0.001 years: could be habitable? no\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1c has a mass of 1.156 Earths, is 0.016AU from its star, and orbits in 0.002 years: could be habitable? no\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1d has a mass of 0.297 Earths, is 0.022AU from its star, and orbits in 0.003 years: could be habitable? no\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1e has a mass of 0.772 Earths, is 0.029AU from its star, and orbits in 0.005 years: could be habitable? yes\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1f has a mass of 0.934 Earths, is 0.038AU from its star, and orbits in 0.007 years: could be habitable? yes\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1g has a mass of 1.148 Earths, is 0.049AU from its star, and orbits in 0.011 years: could be habitable? yes\n" +
        "Planet Trappist1h has a mass of 0.331 Earths, is 0.062AU from its star, and orbits in 0.015 years: could be habitable? no\n";

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //Create our solar system
    SolarSystem ourSystem = new SolarSystem("Our System",1.0);

    //Add planets in our solar system
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Mercury", 0.055, 0.387);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Venus", 0.815, 0.723);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Earth", 1.0, 1.0);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Mars", 0.107, 1.52);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Jupiter", 317.8, 5.20);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Saturn", 95.2, 9.58);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Uranus", 14.5, 19.20);
    ourSystem.addPlanet("Neptune", 17.1, 30.05);

    //Check the output for our solar system
    if (ourSystem.toString().equals(TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN)) {
        System.out.println("Solar System: Pass!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Solar System: Fail!\n*****");
        System.out.println("Expected output:\n");
        System.out.println(TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN);
        System.out.println("\n\nActual output:\n");
        System.out.println(ourSystem.toString());
        // Uncomment if using extra tests*/
        /*System.out.println("\n\nDifferences:");
        System.out.println(StringUtils.difference(ourSystem.toString(),
        TARGET_OUTPUT_SUN));*/
    }

    System.out.println("\n\n");//blank lines to separate output

    //Create the Trappist1 system - a much dimmer star with closer planets
    SolarSystem trappist1 = new SolarSystem("Trappist 1",0.00128);

    //Add planets in Trappist 1 system
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1b", 1.017, 0.012);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1c", 1.156, 0.016);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1d", 0.297, 0.022);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1e", 0.772, 0.029);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1f", 0.934, 0.038);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1g", 1.148, 0.049);
    trappist1.addPlanet("Trappist1h", 0.331, 0.062);

    //Check the output for trappist1
    if (trappist1.toString().equals(TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1)) {
        System.out.println("Trappist1: Pass!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Trappist1: Fail!\n*****");
        System.out.println("Expected output:\n");
        System.out.println(TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1);
        System.out.println("\n\nActual output:\n");
        System.out.println(trappist1.toString());
        // Uncomment if using extra tests*/
        /*System.out.println("\n\nDifferences:");
        System.out.println(StringUtils.difference(ourSystem.toString(),
        TARGET_OUTPUT_TRAPPIST1));*/
    }
}
```

}

In the end after compiling, I'm getting 2 errors in which belong to the same part of a code, saying that contractor can't be apply upload to given types. I'm sorry if I don't see obvious mistake, I spent whole night writing this. Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: change from `public void setSolarSystem` to `public SolarSystem` otherwise you do not have a constructor that takes a `String` and a `double`

Comment: Remove all the `static` declarations from the fields, or they apply to all planets at once rather than one at a time.

Comment: I have posted an answer, I only focused on compile time errors, The rest is in your hands now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just work on compile errors since that's what the question is about and ignore how the code works but will try to make it as close to working.

Okay right of the bat, The first error I see is missing constructor! You did not define a constructor which takes in `String, Double` as the param so here you go.

```
SolarSystem(String solarName, double luminosity) {
    this.solarName = solarName;
    this.luminosity = luminosity;
}
```

You are trying to have static values in a method that is called via instance, I have removed all the static values and fixed calling values statically which you have done.

Your `toString()` method concat is totally messed up so we will fix that aswell.

So here you go, The SolarSystem class with no COMPILE errors.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SolarSystem {
    private double luminosity;
    private String solarName;
    private ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<>();

    SolarSystem(String solarName, double luminosity) {
        this.solarName = solarName;
        this.luminosity = luminosity;
    }

    public double getLuminosity() {
        return luminosity;
    }

    public void setLuminosity(double luminosity) {
        this.luminosity = luminosity;
    }

    public void setSolarSystem(String solarName, double luminosity) {
        this.solarName = solarName;
        this.luminosity = luminosity;
    }

    public String getsolarName() {
        return solarName;
    }

    public String getsolarname() {
        return solarName;
    }

    public void addPlanet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
        Planet newPlanet = new Planet(name, mass, distance);
        planetList.add(newPlanet);
    }

    public String toString() {
        Planet planet = planetList.get(0);
        return getsolarName() + "\n" + "Planet " + planet.getPlanetname() +
                " has a mass of " + planet.getma() + " Earths, is " +
                planet.getdist() + " from its star, and orbits in " +
                planet.getPeriod() +
                " years: could be habitable? " + planet.getHabitable() + "\n";

    }

    class Planet {
        SolarSystem system;
        private String planetname;
        private double ma;
        private double dist;
        private double period;
        private String habitable;
        private double luminos;
        private double sqlum;

        public Planet(String name, double mass, double distance) {
            setPlanetname(name);
            ma = mass;
            dist = distance;
            setLuminosity(luminos);
            period = java.lang.Math.sqrt(distance * distance * distance);
            sqlum = java.lang.Math.sqrt(luminos);
            if ((ma >= 0.6) && (ma <= 7.0) && (dist >= 0.75 * sqlum) && (dist <= 2.0 * sqlum)) {
                habitable = "yes";

            } else {
                habitable = "no";
            }
        }

        public String getdist() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getma() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getPlanetname() {
            return planetname;
        }

        public void setPlanetname(String planetname) {
            this.planetname = planetname;
        }

        public double getPeriod() {
            return period;
        }

        public void setPeriod(double period) {
            this.period = period;
        }

        public String getHabitable() {
            return habitable;
        }

        public void setHabitable(String habitable) {
            this.habitable = habitable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I just need to make it work in the way it will pass the test, but it's going to much easier.

Comment: Just a heads up your toString method is totally messed up and only toString 1 planet. So you need to loop over the list of planets.